# Get the relational data of multiple records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to get the relational data of multiple rows at a time
Like I have table `countries` and `cities` table and in `cities` it has relation with country (some has and some does not have)

So if I want to get all the cities (which have relation with countries) from Country Eloquent is it possible

I have tried something like this

```
Model::where(...)->get()->methods();
```

Or

```
Model::all()->relations;
```

Can we do this ??

Comment: I suppose this is where you use `->has` or `->whereHas` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: "get all cities (which have relation with countries) from Country Eloquent" ... have relation with what country or countries?

Answer (score 1):

use `with()` for eagar load and `has()`

so make sure country has `cities` if there is no `cities` then `Country` will not return

```php
 Country::with('cities')->has('cities')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested eager loading for this.

```
Model::with('cities')->all();
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading